# Why is AngularJS router not triggering?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm trying to trigger a controller for this URL `http://crm.dev/accounts`, I'm  just using an anonymous function in this example for the controller, but the alert inside doesn't get triggered. I can't figure out why, guess it is something stupid I'm missing?

I don't want to use a template or view, I just need to get my controller fired.

Please note that I've already set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('crm', [
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute',
    'angularMoment',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.select',
    'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker'
]);

angular.module('crm').config(function(uiSelectConfig) {
    uiSelectConfig.theme = 'bootstrap';
});

angular.module('crm').constant('angularMomentConfig', {
    preprocess: 'utc',
    timezone: 'Europe/Berlin'
});

angular.module('crm').config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/accounts', {
                controller: function($scope) {
                    alert('TEST');
                }
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
            // enable html5Mode for pushstate ('#'-less URLs)
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    }]);
```

Comment: Make sure to add `templateUrl` and `ngView`.

Comment: If you are using html5 mode, there is some setup that you need on your server as well. Otherwise going directly to that route /accounts, will not work. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: I have this in my Nginx config but it's stil not working.

Comment: Have you define `<base href="/">` within your index.html? @ribsies and @dfsq, he is not using `ui-router` just so you know even if the two work pretty much the same way :)

Comment: html5 mode, and the methods ui-router describe to set it up on your server, are not specific to ui-router. Its for general html5 mode usage.

Comment: The 3 upvotes for this (and 2 other of your questions) seem fishy as they happened on the same minute. http://stackoverflow.com/users/3437727/falk?tab=reputation

Comment: @Falk You enabled html5 mode and also set a hash prefix. If I [read the docs correctly](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes), you should be able to view the working /accounts, regardless of html5 mode, at #!/accounts. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

in your main template, otherwise routing system won't work